# Catching an exception in an overridden method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, exception, error-handling

Why does the following catch block does not catch any exception?
Does this have anything to do with the override->base.Method() relationship?

On the screenshot you can see that an SqlException with a number 2627 is thrown, but the catch block never catches it.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
            Log.Error($"Duplicate key constraint violation occured while submitting changes, {ex.Message}");
            var (resource, duplicateKey) = ExtractDuplicateKeyViolationDetails(ex.Message);
            throw new DuplicateKeyException(resource, duplicateKey);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 547)
        {
            Log.Error($"Constraint violation occured while submitting changes, {ex.Message}");
            var (resource, property) = ExtractConstraintViolationDetails(ex.Message);
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(resource, property);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of it not catching an exception?

Comment: It absolutely should do, so it's likely that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It would only catch an exception that was unhandled or thrown by `base.SaveChanges()`.  If the base implementation handles the exception then you will not receive it in the override.

Comment: I think you thought it's not caching because you throwing the exception on catch block ... comment `throw`

Comment: This is an entity framework 6 DbContext derived class, if this helps.

Comment: Well, [this should work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fQBkAn)

Comment: @Martin well, base implementation re-throws it [base](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs#L349) -> [call](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/InternalContext.cs#L419)

Comment: What actually happens?  Does your app get an unhandled exception?  Does it get caught further up the stack?  Or does it just keep running as if nothing happened?

Comment: This was a dumbed down example. I'll copy the exact code instead.

Comment: That looks fine. You're seeing a first-chance exception: VS is helpfully breaking when it sees the exception *thrown*. Press "Continue", or keep stepping, and it'll step into one of those catch blocks. If you don't want it to break when that exception type is thrown, uncheck "Break when this exception type is thrown" in the "Exception Thrown" dialog in your screenshot (or open up Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings)

Comment: @canton7 I know about this feature, I use it all the time. But still, the code never reaches the inside of the appropriate catch block, even if I keep hitting continue, or if I turn off breaking on exceptions fully.

Comment: @user3548320 It should do. How are you turning off breaking on exceptions fully? Screenshot of the Exception Settings window?

Comment: I untick (black square) the 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' in the Exception Settings window.

Comment: I think I suspect what the issue is. Altough the debugger is showing that an SqlException was thrown if I catch it with a base Exception catcher it showis the following:
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
So it seems like the SqlException is just an inner exception. I just don't know why the debugger shows it the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

You're running your code in debug mode. VS stops execution whenever an exception is thrown and that's what you're seeing. Hit F5 to continue execution and it'll enter the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was the thrown exception was not an SqlException, but a DbUpdateException, where the SqlException was embedded as the InnerException's InnerException...

I've solved it with the following format:

```
    catch (DbUpdateException ex) when (ex.MostInnerException() is SqlException sqlException && sqlException.Number == 2627)
    {
        Log.Error($"Duplicate key constraint violation occured while submitting changes, {sqlException.Message}");
        var (resource, duplicateKey) = ExtractDuplicateKeyViolationDetails(sqlException.Message);
        throw new DuplicateKeyException(resource, duplicateKey);
    }

    internal static Exception MostInnerException(this Exception ex)
    {
        var innerException = ex;

        while (innerException.InnerException != null)
        {
            innerException = innerException.InnerException;
        }

        return innerException;
    }
```